# UITableViewController, cells are reloading incorrectly

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

On my app, once I tap to open all my cells they are all loaded on function by the tableView delegated method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> MyClassName {...}
```

So every time the cells are loaded, this method is called.
By the first time it loads properly (all cells with black background)

[image: image1]

When I go down with the screen and it loads some different cells it also follows my code correctly and loads the cells with white background.

[image: image2]

The problem happens when I go back to the top.

[image: image3]

Its like the number of white background cells are brought up, make the cells once black backgrounded to become white ones (and that's not what I wanted). I thought that once the cells are loaded in the screen, it should stay on device's memory.

I've put some prints on my code to check if they are incorrect but apparently they are working properly.

So I ask you, did any of you had this kind of problem or a similar one? Do you think this is an iOS bug?

EDITED, ADDED CODE:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> HistoricoSelectedCell {
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historicoCell", for: indexPath) as! HistoricoSelectedCell

    let item = itemChosen[indexPath.row].item
    let cell = self.configureCell(cell: cell2, indexPath: indexPath, item: item!)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please add your code. Please read this:: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is a cell re-use issue.

You generate a new cell to use in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` by calling `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: <identifier string>, for: indexPath)` I presume (you really need to post code with your question).

The cell that you get is reused, as in it is not instantiated from scratch but has already been created and used for other cells.

Your options are to:

1) Set all the necessary properties in the `cellForRowAt indexPath` method.

2) Create a `fund configure(cell: UITableViewCell)` function that sets the appropriate properties

3) Override `prepareForReuse()` in your UITableViewClass and restore your properties there.

Comment: Hi Jake, u are right! I've used the dequeue method..
1 - Im setting all the properties on cellForRowAt indexPath method.
2 - Ive created this func to configure now but its been called inside the other method so i dont know where to call it
3 - Ive searched for option 3 but found no method called prepareForReuse()

Check my question again, ive added the code. Do u have another tip? Thanks!